# How to add a where clause to fetchAll in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to return an array of objects like I used to do in CodeIgniter, but now I'm using Zend Framework.  I'm very new at it.  I want to add a where clause to `fetchAll()`.  I tried:

```
$objDocs = new Studyclub_Meetings_Docs();
$this->view->arrDocs = $objDocs->fetchAll(array('meeting_id' => $intMeetingId));
```

but that returns an array of arrays.  How do I return an array of objects?  I'm using ZF 1.x.

Comment: Not enough information, what is your `Studyclub_Meetings_Docs` class? You can check how fetchAll works on ZF 1.x in the [Zend_Db_Table documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html).

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::fetchAll()` which appears to be the variant of `fetchAll()`  you are using accepts a third argument: `$fetchMode`

You probably just need to adjust your code to specify the fetch mode you prefer:

```
$objDocs = new Studyclub_Meetings_Docs();
$this->view->arrDocs = $objDocs->fetchAll(array('meeting_id' => $intMeetingId), Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Good Luck!